Opencv blank white screen on android APK python, kivy app
I'm developing an Android application that uses OpenCV's detection algorithms to analyze images. Currently, I'm testing the app using an Android emulator with an emulated camera since I don't have a physical device for testing yet. All other parts of the app are functioning correctly, but I'm facing an issue where I cannot access the camera with OpenCV.
I've tried using OpenCV's camera module, but I keep getting errors like:
Error: Could not open OpenCV camera at index -1. Trying next index.
Error: Could not open any OpenCV camera.

Is there any specific configuration or setup required to get OpenCV's camera working with the Android emulator?
I’ve also considered using Plyer to access the camera, but I’m unsure if it’s compatible with OpenCV’s image processing capabilities. Would using Plyer be a viable solution in this case?
Any help would be much appreciated!
The main thing I've tried is trying different cv2.VideoCapture ids but none seems to work as well as different configurations for how python interacts with the kivy file.
**
requirements.txt file:
**
appdirs==1.4.4
build==1.2.2.post1
buildozer==1.5.0
certifi==2024.8.30
charset-normalizer==3.4.0
colorama==0.4.6
Cython==3.0.11
distlib==0.3.9
docutils==0.21.2
filelock==3.16.1
idna==3.10
Jinja2==3.1.4
Kivy==2.3.0
Kivy-Garden==0.1.5
kivymd==1.1.1
MarkupSafe==3.0.2
numpy==2.1.3
opencv-python==4.10.0.84
packaging==24.2
pexpect==4.9.0
pillow==10.4.0
platformdirs==4.3.6
plyer==2.1.0
ptyprocess==0.7.0
Pygments==2.18.0
pyjnius==1.5.0
pyproject_hooks==1.2.0
python-for-android==2024.1.21
requests==2.32.3
sh==1.14.3
six==1.16.0
toml==0.10.2
urllib3==2.2.3
virtualenv==20.27.1

**
python file only camera function:
**
import cv2



from kivy.app import App 

from kivy.lang import Builder #building files correctly

from kivy.uix.button import Button #for the buttons

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout # for the layout (there are different types of layouts in kivy this is just the most basic one)

from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout # for non dynamic layout so the buttons dont move for camera page

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen #for the screen manager to track which screen is being shown 

from kivy.uix.label import Label # for the label like headers 

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget # adds widget for each of the classes

from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown # adds dropdown widgets

from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Rectangle # adds color to the circle

from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture #used for OpenCV image data

from kivy.core.window import Window # Sets the background color for app

from kivy.uix.camera import Camera  #Kivy's built-in Camera widget

from kivy.uix.popup import Popup #For dialog window for popups when needed

from kivy.uix.image import Image #Widgets for displaying selected images

from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, StringProperty # control text values

from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex # color translating from hex to rgba

from plyer import filechooser #From plyer library for image selection

from PIL import Image as PILImage #Python Image Library

from PIL import ImageDraw, ImageFont #Python Image Library

from kivy.clock import Clock #Used to capture frames form OpenCV Camera

import os #Python module for operating system interactions

import numpy as np #Used for handling image data from OpenCV's numpy arrays

from kivy.utils import platform



if platform == "android":

    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission

    request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.CAMERA, Permission.INTERNET])

     

class CameraPage(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(CameraPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    

        self.cap = None  # OpenCV VideoCapture

        self.image_cache = None

        self.frame_event = None

        self.current_frame = None # Captures the current frame



    # Start OpenCV camera when user is in the camera page

    def on_enter(self, *args):

        self.start_opencv_camera()



    # Stop OpenCV camera when user exits the camera page

    def on_leave(self, *args):

        if self.cap:

            self.cap.release()  # Release the camera

            print("Camera has been released.")

        if self.frame_event:

            self.frame_event.cancel()  # Cancel frame update



    # Start OpenCV camera

    def start_opencv_camera(self):

        camera_indices = [0, 1, 2]  # List of indices to try for camera

        self.cap = None  # Initialize VideoCapture as None

    

        # Try opening cameras in the order specified in the list

        for index in camera_indices:

            self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(index)

            if self.cap.isOpened():

                print(f"OpenCV camera started on index {index}.")

                break  # If successful, exit the loop

            else:

                print(f"Error: Could not open OpenCV camera at index {index}. Trying next index.")

        

        # If camera still isn't opened, log the error

        if not self.cap or not self.cap.isOpened():

            print("Error: Could not open any OpenCV camera.")

        else:

            # Schedule the update of camera frames by 30 FPS

            self.frame_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_camera_feed, 1.0 / 30.0)



    # Update the Image widget with the camera feed

    def update_camera_feed(self, dt):

        if self.cap:

            ret, frame = self.cap.read()

            if ret:

                self.current_frame = frame  # Store the current frame

                # Convert BGR frame to RGB

                buf = cv2.flip(frame, 0).tobytes()

                texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')

                texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')

                self.ids.camera_feed.texture = texture



    # Capture image using the current frame from OpenCV

    def capture_opencv_image(self):

        if self.current_frame is not None:

            # Convert OpenCV frame (BGR) to PIL Image (RGB)

            pil_image = PILImage.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(self.current_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))



            # Save to cache directory

            cache_dir = './image_cache'

            if not os.path.exists(cache_dir):

                os.mkdir(cache_dir)

            cached_image_path = os.path.join(cache_dir, 'captured_image.png')

            pil_image.save(cached_image_path)

            self.image_cache = cached_image_path

            print(f"Image captured and cached at: {cached_image_path}")

        else:

            print("Error: No frame available to capture")



    # Function that opens gallery works for windows and should work for android

    def open_gallery(self, *args):

        # Opens the file chooser to select images

        filechooser.open_file(on_selection=self.display_image)



    # Display the selected image in a popup

    def display_image(self, selection):

        if selection:

            # Cache for the selected image

            self.image_cache = selection[0]

            # Create/open popup

            image_popup = ImagePopup()

            image_popup.ids.img.source = self.image_cache

            image_popup.open()



    # Cache the selected image

    def cache_image(self, instance):

        # Checks if cache location exists

        if self.image_cache:

            cache_dir = './image_cache'  # Cache directory

            if not os.path.exists(cache_dir):

                os.mkdir(cache_dir)  # Create cache location if does not existing



            # Select a location/path for the cached image

            cached_image_path = os.path.join(cache_dir, 'cached_image.png')

            try:

                with open(self.image_cache, 'rb') as source_file:

                    with open(cached_image_path, 'wb') as dest_file:

                        dest_file.write(source_file.read())



                print(f"Image cached at: {cached_image_path}")

            except Exception as e:

                print(f"Error caching the image: {e}")

        else:

            print("Error: No image selected for caching")


**
kivy file:
**
#:kivy 1.0



ScreenManager:

    FrontPage:

    SettingsPage:

    CameraPage:

    ManualPage:



<FrontPage>:

    name: 'front_page'

    FloatLayout:

        #size: root.width - 200, root.height - 200

        #pos: 100, 100 

        orientation: 'vertical'



        Label:

            text: 'Block Lens'

            font_size: 50

            pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.7}

            # Will add font style to the title

        RoundedButton:

            text: 'Go to settings page'

            on_press: app.root.current = 'settings_page'

            #shrinks the button and adjust the button based on x axis and y axis

            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.2, 'center_y': 0.5}

            size: 200, 200

        RoundedButton:

            text: 'Go to camera page'

            on_press: app.root.current = 'camera_page'

            #shrinks the button

            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.8, 'center_y': 0.5}

            size: 200, 200

        RoundedButton:

            text: 'Go to manual page'

            on_press: app.root.current = 'manual_page'

            #shrinks the button

            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3}

            size: 200, 200

<SettingsPage>:

    name: 'settings_page'





    # TOP LAYOUT SET UP - BACK BUTTON AND SETTINGS BANNER

    BoxLayout:

        orientation: 'vertical'

        

        # SETTING LAYOUT

        FloatLayout:

            size_hint_y: None

            height: '50dp'

        

            # BACK BUTTON LAYOUT

            Button:

                id: back_button

                text: 'Back'

                background_color: app.get_color("Text Color")  # White background for button

                color: app.get_color("Border Color") #black text for button

                border: app.get_color("Border Color")

                size_hint: None, None

                size: '50dp', '30dp' 

                pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top": 1}

                on_release: app.root.current = 'front_page'



            # LABEL

            Label:

                id: settings_label

                text: 'Settings'

                font_size: app.text_size_labels

                color: app.get_color("Text Color")

                size_hint_y: None

                height: '25dp' 

                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "top": 0.8}





        # SCROLL SETTINGS SETUP

        ScrollView:

            id: scroll_view

            do_scroll_x: False

            canvas.before:

                Color:

                    rgba: app.get_color("Background Color")

                Rectangle:

                    pos: self.pos

                    size: self.size



            # SETTING UP SCROLLABLE AREA

            BoxLayout:

                id: settings_container

                orientation: 'vertical'

                size_hint_y: None

                height: self.minimum_height

                

                # SETTINGS WIDGETS HERE

                # Text Settings

                BoxLayout:

                    orientation: 'horizontal'

                    size_hint_y: None

                    height: '40dp'



                    Label:

                        text: "Text Size"

                        font_size: app.text_size_default_font

                        color: app.get_color("Text Color")

                        size_hint_y: None

                        size_hint_x: 0.4

                        height: '40dp'

                    

                    Button:

                        id: text_size_small

                        text: "Small"

                        font_size: app.text_size_default_font

                        background_color: app.get_color("Non-Selected Color") if self.text != app.text_size_default_font else app.get_color("Selected Box Color")

                        color: app.get_color("Text Color")

                        size_hint_x: 0.2

                        on_release: app.set_font_size('Small')

                    

                    Button:

                        id: text_size_default

                        text: "Default"

                        font_size: app.text_size_default_font

                        background_color: app.get_color("Non-Selected Color") if self.text != app.text_size_default_font else app.get_color("Selected Box Color")

                        color: app.get_color("Text Color")

                        size_hint_x: 0.2

                        on_release: app.set_font_size('Default')



                    Button:

                        id: text_size_large

                        text: "Large"

                        font_size: app.text_size_default_font

                        font_size: app.text_size_default_font

                        background_color: app.get_color("Non-Selected Color") if self.text != app.text_size_default_font else app.get_color("Selected Box Color")

                        color: app.get_color("Text Color")

                        size_hint_x: 0.2

                        on_release: app.set_font_size('Large')

                

                #COLORBLIND WIDGET HERE

                BoxLayout:

                    orientation: 'horizontal'

                    size_hint_y: None

                    height: '40dp'



                    Label:

                        text: "Color Blind Mode"

                        font_size: app.text_size_default_font

                        color: app.get_color("Text Color")

                        size_hint_y: None

                        height: '40dp'



                    Button:

                        id: color_blind_button

                        text: 'Default'

                        font_size: app.text_size_default_font

                        background_color: app.get_color("Non-Selected Color")

                        color: app.get_color("Text Color")

                        size_hint_y: None

                        height: '40dp'





                Label:

                    text: "Summary Text-To-Speech"

                    font_size: app.text_size_default_font

                    color: app.get_color("Text Color")

                    size_hint_y: None

                    height: '40dp'

                

                Label:

                    text: 'About Us'

                    font_size: app.text_size_labels

                    color: app.get_color("Text Color")

                    size_hint_y: None

                    height: '25dp' 

                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "top": 1}

                Label:

                    text: root.about_us_text

                    font_size: app.text_size_default_font

                    color: app.get_color("Text Color")

                    size_hint_y: None

                    text_size: self.width, None

                    halign: 'left'

                    valign: 'top'

                    height: self.texture_size[1]



<CameraPage>:

    name: 'camera_page'

    FloatLayout:

        Image:

            id: camera_feed

            size_hint: (1, 0.8)

            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'top': 1}

        

        Button:

            text: 'Capture'

            size_hint: (0.3, 0.1)

            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0.2}

            on_press: root.capture_opencv_image()



        BoxLayout:

            orientation: 'horizontal'

            size_hint_y: None

            height: '50dp'

            pos_hint: {'bottom': 1}



            Button:

                text: 'Go to front page'

                on_press: app.root.current = 'front_page'



            Button:

                text: 'Gallery'

                on_press: root.open_gallery()


<ManualPage>:

    name: 'manual_page'

    BoxLayout:

        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:

            text: 'Welcome to the manual page'

            font_size: 20

        Button:

            text: 'Go to front page'

            on_press: app.root.current = 'front_page'


**
error code from logcat:
**
              V  onWindowFocusChanged(): false
2024-12-02 01:36:12.928 10575-10575 SDL                     org.test.myapp                       V  nativeFocusChanged()
2024-12-02 01:36:13.256   586-610   WindowManager           system_server                        V  Sent Transition (#180) createdAt=12-02 01:36:12.833 via request=TransitionRequestInfo { type = OPEN, triggerTask = TaskInfo{userId=0 taskId=45 displayId=0 isRunning=true baseIntent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity } baseActivity=ComponentInfo{org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity} topActivity=ComponentInfo{com.google.android.permissioncontroller/com.android.permissioncontroller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity} origActivity=null realActivity=ComponentInfo{org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity} numActivities=2 lastActiveTime=17100318 supportsMultiWindow=true resizeMode=1 isResizeable=true minWidth=-1 minHeight=-1 defaultMinSize=220 token=WCT{RemoteToken{24afd65 Task{4cf9d18 #45 type=standard A=10242:org.test.myapp}}} topActivityType=1 pictureInPictureParams=null shouldDockBigOverlays=false launchIntoPipHostTaskId=-1 lastParentTaskIdBeforePip=-1 displayCutoutSafeInsets=null topActivityInfo=ActivityInfo{cd97023 com.android.permissioncontroller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity} launchCookies=[android.os.BinderProxy@4f6c6eb] positionInParent=Point(0, 0) parentTaskId=-1 isFocused=true isVisible=true isVisibleRequested=true isSleeping=false locusId=null displayAreaFeatureId=1 isTopActivityTransparent=true appCompatTaskInfo=AppCompatTaskInfo { topActivityInSizeCompat=false topActivityEligibleForLetterboxEducation= falseisLetterboxEducationEnabled= true isLetterboxDoubleTapEnabled= false topActivityEligibleForUserAspectRatioButton= false topActivityBoundsLetterboxed= false isFromLetterboxDoubleTap= false topActivityLetterboxVerticalPosition= -1 topActivityLetterboxHorizontalPosition= -1 topActivityLetterboxWidth=1080 topActivityLetterboxHeight=2400 isUserFullscreenOverrideEnabled=false isSystemFullscreenOverrideEnabled=false cameraCompatTaskInfo=CameraCompatTaskInfo { cameraCompatControlState=hidden freeformCameraCompatMode=inactive}}}, pipTask = null, remoteTransition = null, displayChange = null, flags = 0, debugId = 180 }
2024-12-02 01:36:13.397 10575-10575 PythonActivity          org.test.myapp                       V  onRequestPermissionsResult()
2024-12-02 01:36:13.398 10575-10575 PythonActivity          org.test.myapp                       V  onRequestPermissionsResult passed to callback
2024-12-02 01:36:13.433 10575-10575 PythonActivity          org.test.myapp                       V  onResume()
2024-12-02 01:36:13.433 10575-10575 SDL                     org.test.myapp                       V  onResume()
2024-12-02 01:36:13.449 10575-10599 python                  org.test.myapp                       I  [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
2024-12-02 01:36:13.452 10575-10599 python                  org.test.myapp                       I  [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
2024-12-02 01:36:13.502 10575-10575 SDL                     org.test.myapp                       V  onWindowFocusChanged(): true
2024-12-02 01:36:13.504 10575-10575 SDL                     org.test.myapp                       V  nativeFocusChanged()
2024-12-02 01:36:13.618   586-716   ImeTracker              system_server                        I  org.test.myapp:e80cb21b: onRequestHide at ORIGIN_SERVER reason HIDE_SAME_WINDOW_FOCUSED_WITHOUT_EDITOR fromUser false
2024-12-02 01:36:13.618   586-716   ImeTracker              system_server                        I  org.test.myapp:e80cb21b: onCancelled at PHASE_SERVER_SHOULD_HIDE
2024-12-02 01:36:13.626 10575-10599 python                  org.test.myapp                       I  [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
2024-12-02 01:36:13.626  1273-1273  GoogleInpu...hodService com...gle.android.inputmethod.latin  I  GoogleInputMethodService.onStartInput():1899 onStartInput(EditorInfo{EditorInfo{packageName=org.test.myapp, inputType=0, inputTypeString=NULL, enableLearning=false, autoCorrection=false, autoComplete=false, imeOptions=0, privateImeOptions=null, actionName=UNSPECIFIED, actionLabel=null, initialSelStart=-1, initialSelEnd=-1, initialCapsMode=0, label=null, fieldId=0, fieldName=null, extras=null, hintText=null, hintLocales=[]}}, false)
2024-12-02 01:36:13.631   586-1918  PackageConfigPersister  system_server                        W  App-specific configuration not found for packageName: org.test.myapp and userId: 0
2024-12-02 01:36:20.387 10575-10599 python                  org.test.myapp                       I  Error: Could not open OpenCV camera at index -1. Trying next index.
2024-12-02 01:36:20.387 10575-10599 python                  org.test.myapp                       I  Error: Could not open OpenCV camera at index 0. Trying next index.
2024-12-02 01:36:20.387 10575-10599 python                  org.test.myapp                       I  Error: Could not open OpenCV camera at index 1. Trying next index.
2024-12-02 01:36:20.387 10575-10599 python                  org.test.myapp                       I  Error: Could not open OpenCV camera at index 2. Trying next index.
2024-12-02 01:36:20.388 10575-10599 python                  org.test.myapp                       I  Error: Could not open any OpenCV camera.
2024-12-02 01:36:21.097 10575-10599 python                  org.test.myapp                       I  Error: No frame available to capture
2024-12-02 01:36:21.123 10575-10599 EGL_emulation           org.test.myapp                       D  app_time_stats: avg=468.48ms min=4.96ms max=5895.82ms count=15
2024-12-02 01:36:22.445 10575-10599 EGL_emulation           org.test.myapp                       D  app_time_stats: avg=660.67ms min=67.26ms max=1254.09ms count=2
2024-12-02 01:36:22.863 10575-10599 python                  org.test.myapp                       I  Camera has been released.
2024-12-02 01:36:23.909 10575-10599 EGL_emulation           org.test.myapp                       D  app_time_stats: avg=125.97ms min=5.73ms max=997.70ms count=11
2024-12-02 01:36:24.960 10575-10599 EGL_emulation           org.test.myapp                       D  app_time_stats: avg=28.44ms min=5.08ms max=110.71ms count=29

